# Saving and retrieving photos in MySql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I would like to get a picture from the user and insert into the database. The user should upload the file in the below input field. Also, I would like to display the image from the database when I require.

```
<label>Photo</label>
<input type="file" name="photo" required>
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", ""); mysql_select_db("prs");
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $photo = $_FILES['photo']['name'];
    {
        $query = mysql_query("insert into date (photo) values ('$photo')");
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: upload the image on server. Save its path in database and pull it from the URL while displaying

Comment: Can you please explain it

Comment: First refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13470482/php-upload-image-to-directory)

Comment: After doing this, you have to get image name from you table and get that file from your upload folder

Comment: first off, mysql_connect has been deprecated. Please use mysqli_connect

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by below process

1. Upload the images to the server. you can save it in images folder or where you want.
2. Only store the uploaded image path at the database. ex. /image/default.png. You can also save only image name as database ex. default.png
3. Retrieve the image path from database when you want to display the image.
4. You can display the image in web page using image tag
   ex. `<img src="../images/default.png" />`

Answer (score 0):

The best thing is to save file path or the file name in your database table. And save your file in the server.

Here is a sample MULTIPLE image uploading and retrieving script for your need. I'm going to use 3 files here. front.html, upload.php and finally preview.php

1. Front.html

This file contains the basic html form content .

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="upload.php" method="post">
<input id="uploadFile" type="file" name="files[]"  class="img" />
<button class="btn btn-primary" name="up_img">POST</button>
</form>
```

2.upload.php

```
if(isset($_POST['up_img'])){ $errors= array();

    foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
        $file_name =$key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
        $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];

        if($file_size > 2097152){
            $errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';
        }
        $pType='I';
        $query="insert into img(user,FILE_NAME)values('$sUser','$file_name') ";
        $desired_dir="images_folder";
        if(empty($errors)==true){
            if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
                mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);        // Create directory if it does not exist
            }
            if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false){
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"$desired_dir/".$file_name);
            }else{                                  // rename the file if another one exist
                $new_dir="$desired_dir/".$file_name.time();
                 rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ;               
            }
         mysql_query($query);           
        }else{
                print_r($errors);
        }
    }
    if(empty($error)){
    header('Location:preview.php');
    }

    }
```

3.preview.php

Now I have successfully uploaded my image/images to the server and ready to retrieve them. remember my images files are now stored in the folder call images_folder and their paths are saved in img table.

```
<?php
$sql=mysql_query('SELECT * FROM img ');
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
$sPic=$row['FILE_NAME'];  

echo '<img src="images_folder/'.$sPic.'">';

}
?>
```

That's it. That is how you are going to upload images to your server, and retrieve them.

Answer (score 0):

So here is a little option to upload a picture and save the picture into mysql
this is not tested just typed.

```
if(isset($_FILES['picture']) //checks for form post if not show form
    {
        $title = $_POST['title']; //get title
        $desc = $_POST['description']; //get description
        $target = "downloads/pics/".basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name']);  //this gets the target folder to save pictures make sure folder exists
        $ok=1; //basic error set to 1
        //This is our size condition 
        if ($uploaded_size > 20000000) 
        { 
            $out = "Your file is too large.<br>"; //checks for file size this can be changed to w/e
            $ok=0; //if over error is set to 0
        } 
        if ($ok==0) 
        { 
            $out.= "Sorry your file was not uploaded"; 
            return $out;
        } 
        //If everything is ok we try to upload it 
        else 
        { 
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'], $target)) //tires to move the uploaded picture to target
            { 
                $out = "The Picture: <b><u>".basename( $_FILES['picture']['name']). "</b></u> has been uploaded";  //if successfull then post was uploaded
                $sql = "INSERT INTO database SET title=\"".$title."\",picture=\"".basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name'])."\",description=\"".$desc."\""; //sql string to insert the folder and picture name
                    if (!mysql_query($sql))
                    {
                        die('Error In Picture Upload: - SQL INSERT INTO - '.date('m-d-y').' - SQL ERROR: '.mysql_error()); //if mysql error post error
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $out.="<br /><br />Return To Your <a href=\"return location\">Downloads</a>"; //if mysql is ok show the return link
                        return $out;
                    }
            } 
        }
    else // if form is not submited then show form
    {
        $out ="\t\t<h3>".ucwords('new picture')."</h3>\r\n";
        $out.="\t\t<form name=\"post\" action=\"".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."\" method=\"post\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\">\r\n";
        $out.="\t\t\t<p>Title:<br /><input type=\"text\" class=\"inputtext\" name=\"title\" value=\"\" /></p>\r\n";
        $out.="\t\t\t<p><b>".ucwords('picture upload')."</b>: <input type=\"file\" name=\"picture\" /></p>\r\n";
        $out.="\t\t\t<p>Description:<br /><textarea id=\"text9\" name=\"description\"></textarea></p>\r\n";
        $out.="\t\t\t<p><input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"".ucwords('upload')."\" /></p>\r\n";
        $out.="\t\t</form>\r\n";
        echo $out;
    }
```