# posting of dataurl to php

Tags: php, ajax

```
ajax.open("POST", "upload.php", true);
  ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
//ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "image/png",1);
  ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
        alert(ajax.responseText);
      }
  }
  ajax.send("imgData=" + canvasData);
}
```

This is the xmlhttprequest that sends the data to upload.php which says that it is unable to save the file. However the php page saves the file with 0B.

```
<?php   
  
// Requires php5   
define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'images/');   
$img = $_POST['canvasData']; 
print $img;
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);   
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);   
$data = base64_decode($img);   
$file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.png';   
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);   
print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.';   
  
?>
```

Above being the php file to which the data gets posted......

Comment: can you elaborate the problem you are facing?

Comment: Hi, first thnx for taking interest. i am trying to upload a canvas image file that i captured from the webcam using xmlhttprequest. i have converted the image file to base64 format using toDataUrl method. the image is getting posted as form data when i look at the header. However, when the php file code mentioned above is executed...i see only a 0B image uploaded to the server folder('images'). Along with the error invalid file. why is the data not accessible by my php file...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upload file into directory use `move_uploaded_file` function , but your question unclear , check the following post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13470868/13143492)

Comment: Hi, first thnx for taking interest. i am trying to upload a canvas image file that i captured from the webcam using xmlhttprequest. i have converted the image file to base64 format using toDataUrl method. the image is getting posted as form data when i look at the header. However, when the php file code mentioned above is executed...i see only a 0B image uploaded to the server folder('images'). Along with the error invalid file. why is the data not accessible by my php file...

Comment: Your image probably is still a blob type you must convert blob to file (png,jpg etc)

Comment: Thnx, i found an elegant solution by posting the data url in a hidden field